# MS SQL 2008 "could not find stored procedure"

Tags: sql-server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хранимые процедуры в базе данных существуют, а в сценарии их не все видно.
В чем проблема???

Comment: Вы пробовали их запускать?

Comment: да. они рабочие

Comment: Попробуйте `Edit->Intellisense->Refresh Local Cache`

Comment: хм... спасибо. помогло

Answer (score 2):

Напишу еще раз как ответ. Необходимо обновить локальный кэш:

```
Edit->Intellisense->Refresh Local Cache
```

Или комбинация клавиш: `Ctrl + Shift + R`

Answer (score 1):

Выбирай в списке наверху правильную базу, а не `master`.

По идее, `use` в коде это делает, но, похоже, подсветка осталась от `master`а.